# Different Android app version in different countries

Tags: android, publishing

I have an app that needs to be approved by certain regulatory agencies in different countries before it can be released.  I don't see a way to pick when an update goes live to a particular country on the Play Store.  Is this possible?

So for example, let's say I have Foo 1.0 on the Play Store now.  I want to release Foo 1.1 in the USA, but delay it in Canada for a year because I have to get it approved by their regulatory agency first.  Is there a way to do that without having a "Foo USA" and a "Foo Canada" as separate apps?

Answer (score 2):

You could create multiple google play store entries, restrict them by country. That would require creating different apps that would use the same code and only differ in package name and singing keys that would come from flavours config.

But that would have con of having multiple store entries, which effectively be separate apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We've considered this option as a last resort.  Another option we ran into was the Staged Rollout feature which may be good enough.

Comment: Is this option feasible? How can you handle different package names in the same codebase?